What else can be done to manage work stress and mental health issues?
For the past couple of months been dealing with mental health issues (General Anxiety & Severe Depression), diagnosed by a healthcare provider.
I decided to bring my situation to my supervisor's attention since it was affecting my performance at work and attendance. I also spoke up about feeling discriminated by my manager due to my medical condition.
He advised me to file for personal leave so I can have a mental break, and once done he wanted me to let him know personally so he can approve.
I called off the very next day & filed for personal leave and sadly once I tried to get in touch with him about it he ghosted me. I also got in touch with HR about the situation and instead of helping me they basically took it as a he said / she said circumstance, in other words not believing that I had spoken to my supervisor about it so “they couldn’t do anything”.
Instead I chose the option to file for short term disability since my mental health issues got more severe and I had been calling off for the time being.
Both my personal leave and short term disability got denied since mental health ain’t a serious medical disability in their eyes.
I feel as I’m getting retaliated against for speaking up.
I'm due to go back to work soon. I don’t know if I should go back or not or just quit.
What should I do?
I’m in the USA.

What kinds of options are you looking for?  Note that requesting special consideration on the basis of mental health, as for any other medical condition, requires a doctor's diagnosis and recommendations. If it's just self-diagnosis... well, catching your breath is one of the things vacation days are for.

What size company, it matters. Also, please remember HR is never your friend.

If your "healthcare provider" is a medical doctor or psychiatrist (someone with a Ph.D and licenses to practice medicine), then you should do the following:
You should try to get an official document from the doctor to present to your HR. That document should also recommend that you take a short term disability break from work, and request that your company allow you to take that short term disability break. This document may help to convince HR a lot more than just your own words.

Note: I turned my comment into an answer per the moderator's suggestion.

I suspect you mean MD not PhD, as someone with the latter is very unlikely to have a license to practice medicine.

Psychologists -- which is not the profession I would consult at this stage -- are often PhD. Psychiatrists are doctors and so have an MD, and I would suggest starting with them. Get yourself stabilized first, then a psychologist may be able to help you improve your coping skills.  But I'm sure a good portion of the readers will disagree with me.

I think the key here is to decide what is your desired end state.  Where do you want to be 5 years from now?  Do you want to be living off of social security disability or working on your career.
If you seek disability, get in touch with a lawyer that specializes in that area and work through that process.  It is a tough life, as very little income is provided by this program.
If you seek to be a person fulfilling their career aspirations, then you need to stop playing the victim and take charge of your life.  I am not medical professional and do believe that mental issues are real, but so is responsibility.  Did you walk out of that "health care provider" with a prescription?  Did you get it filled?  Drugs like zoloft help those suffering from depression function without many side effects.  The drug is also inexpensive in the US.
Get a script, take it, and get on with your life.  You can do this.
